# My Perl split function is returning individual numbers and characters. How can I fix this?

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I've got a character string that looks like this:

`803|804` and `7|7`

This is my PERL code:

`my @vpid = split /|/, $vpid;
 my @quantity = split('|', $quantity);`

My results are:

`8 0 3 | 8 0 4` and `7 | 7`.

The results I'm looking for are `803 804` and `7 7` as the content of the arrays.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this question related to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24245935/716443  ...the similarity (`@vpid` vs `@id`, and the pipe-delimited integers) in such close time-proximity to that other question is spooky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a regex special character denoting "or".  You must escape it.

```
my @vpid = split /\|/, '803|804';
my @quantity = split '\|', '7|7';

use Data::Dump;
dd @vpid;
dd @quantity;
```

Outputs:

```
(803, 804)
(7, 7)
```

Comment: You should use the first one (`/\|/`) consistently. Split with a string argument is the kind of thing that only works "by mistake" and probably doesn't do what you want it to.